# How to retrieve/extract XML element attribute value

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML like the following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PaymentElement>
        <Payment seqID="3">
            <TPayment>
                <Status>status</Status>
            </TPayment>
        </Payment>
    </PaymentElement>
```

The question is how do I retrieve/extract seqID value which is 3 out of this via java.

I have tried the following way, but it doesn't work.

```
InputStream xml = conn.getInputStream(); 
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(xml);
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("PaymentElement");

for(int i=0; i<=list.getLength();i++){
    NodeList paySeq=doc.getElementsByTagName("Payment seqID");
System.out.println("Payment seqID"+paySeq);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/PaymentElement/Payment/@seqID");
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

`result` should be having `3` now.

**Full Example**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("sample.xml");
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(inputStream);
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/PaymentElement/Payment/@seqID");
        Object result = expr.evaluate(inputSource, XPathConstants.STRING);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: result is blank value 3 is not coming

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream xml = new FileInputStream("sample.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(xml);
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/PaymentElement/Payment/@seqID");
        Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

Comment: @RKajaMohideen - +1, I also added a modified version of your comment to your answer.  The change I made was to eliminate the conversion to DOM.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan That's perfectly fine. I just provided the solution for the issue he's trying to solve. I didn't concentrate on DOM part :-)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new File("1.xml"));
    Element e  = (Element)doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("Payment").item(0);
    String id = e.getAttribute("seqID");
    System.out.println("Payment seqID = " + id);
```

output

```
 Payment seqID = 3
```

Comment: I copypasted the full version in the answer, try again